# two fixed effect question

Tags: regression, econometrics, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I was reading this journal article on two way fixed effects by Michelle M. Marcus &  Pedro H. C. Sant'Anna

The Role of Parallel Trends in Event Study Settings: An Application to Environmental Economics
https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/711509

It says

The canonical DID method presumes the

- existence of two groups, the treated and the comparison group,
- two time periods, pretreatment and posttreatment periods, s
  such that the comparison group is not treated in either time period, and
  the treated group is only treated at the posttreatment period.
  Then, one estimates the average treatment effect among those treated units by comparing the average difference in pre- and posttreatment outcomes of two groups or, equivalently, by using a two-way fixed effects regression model with a group and a time fixed effect;

Here’s an example of how such a data looks like.

```
###### Generate random heights and weights
heights <- rnorm(1000, mean = 170, sd = 10)  # Random heights (mean=170, sd=10)
weights <- rnorm(1000, mean = 70, sd = 5)   # Random weights (mean=70, sd=5)

###### Calculate BMI
bmi <- weights / ((heights / 100) ^ 2) 

years       <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018,  2019,  2020, 2021)
percentages <- c(0.1,  0.71, 0.4,  0.45, 0.58, 0.72, 0.15, 0.8,  2.35, 3.79, 3.82, 4.12, 4.59, 4.10, 5.87, 7.13, 8.67, 9.07, 16.23, 22.19, 2.28, 1.81)

Year <- sample(rep(years, round(length(years) * percentages)), 1000, replace = TRUE)

Z <- ifelse(Year > "2017",1,0)

testdf <- as.data.frame(cbind(bmi, Year,Z))

table(testdf$Year, testdf$Z)


         0   1
  2000   1   0
  2001   6   0
  2002   3   0
  2003   9   0
  2004  10   0
  2005   5   0
  2007   8   0
  2008  29   0
  2009  35   0
  2010  49   0
  2011  41   0
  2012  36   0
  2013  35   0
  2014  72   0
  2015  66   0
  2016  92   0
  2017 104   0
  2018   0 150
  2019   0 208
  2020   0  24
  2021   0  17
```

How is it possible to fit a two fixed effects model $y_{i,t}$ = $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1$$Z_i$ + $\beta_2$$t$ + $\beta_3$$Z_{it}$ as mentioned by Michelle & Sant'Anna when $Z_i$ {0 or 1 treatment indicator} and time $t_i$ are multi-collinear ?

I am stuck here and would greatly appreciate any advise. Thanks in advance.

Response to Tomas suggestions

- i represents each individual subject(child)
- y is outcome BMI
- t time in years
- Exchangeability: Although we have only BMI(outcome) measured once for 99% of the subjects, during either the pre or post period, I am relying on the exchangeability assumption. Because subjects during the pre-treatment era(before 2017) and treatment (2017) were randomly selected, I am assuming exchangeability holds

Comment: I have two concerns I would like to address. First, what are your units $i$? In other words, what does $Z_{i}$ represent in your equation? Second, the policy variable doesn't really vary across $i$; it varies over time. I only see a shock *after* 2017. In a setting like this, the time fixed effects will absorb the policy variable. Before I can begin to help, what denotes the "unit" in your case? Shouldn't we be observing the BMI of "individuals" over time, where for some the policy applies and for others it does not?

Comment: I am very confused by your code and the model statement.  First, weight and height won't both be random, they are correlated. Second, what is your Year variable? Third, your model has y (not mentioned before, maybe it is BMI?) as the DV and only Z (which can only be 0 or 1, as DV. Fourth, the collinearity in your table seems due to how you constructed the data, not anything inherent in the situation.

Comment: One more thing, what are your "percentages"?

Comment: @ThomasBilach, Hi Tomas, Excellent questions. I have updated my question section based on your suggestions. Please let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: @PeterFlom, Dear Peter my apologies for the confusion. You are correct about height&weight. I am simulating Ht&Wt only to estimate BMI which is the outcome. Z is the policy or in this case event indicator (0,1) 0= Pre 2017 and 1=2017 and later. My goal is to estimate the change in BMI among subjects(children) before 2017 (z=0) vs BMI among children 2017 or later. Any suggestions for how restructure the data is highly appreciated.

Comment: I would use a multilevel model.